# C Programming- Pointers

Tags: c

I came across the following code, the output for which is 0.

Is the statement `vptr = &i` correct? Can we assign a `void` pointer, address of an integer variable?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void fun(void *p);
int i;

int main()
{
    void *vptr;
    vptr = &i;
    fun(vptr);
    return 0;
}
void fun(void *p)
{
    int **q;
    q = (int**)&p;
    printf("%d\n", **q);
}
```

Comment: Define _"correct"_. Syntax? Semantics? Usage? Behavior? Practice?

Comment: A void pointer can be assigned a memory address of anything. It is sometimes used in C to program "generics"

Comment: @SouravGhosh correct means its behaviour, can we assign an integer type memory to void using the above statement?

Answer (score 8):

The statement `vptr = &i;` is fine.

However, the statement `q = (int**)&p;` is incorrect.  `&p` does not point at an `int*`, it points at a `void*`.  It is not guaranteed that `int*` and `void*` have compatible layouts.

A correct implementation of `fun` would be

```
void fun(void *p)
{
    printf("%d\n", *(int*)p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any pointer type can be converted into `void*`.
From the [C standard 6.3.2.3p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p1):

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any object
>   type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to
>   void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original
>   pointer.